# GTK problem with wrong library

Tags: dll, gtk

I have build program which uses GTK 2.22.1 and I wanted to share it with my friend. I packed all DLL's in the same as .exe directory but my friend gets the following error:

> Error: Didn't find ordinal number 73 in
>   dynamic library zlib1.dll

It's translation from Poland so it is probably not the same as it would be in ENG version of Window but I think you get the idea. I wanted to search something on GTK site but it seems to be down.

Answer (score 2):

One of the libraries you packed needs a specific version of *zlib1.dll*. Don't forget to send that to your friend too.